# Checkbox state not changed ASP- vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I want to create a page that has one image/button. When you click on it. 
It will appear one pop up window with few check box inside. And I want to pass the value of the checkbox to a label when it is checked.

But The checkbox's CHECKEDCHANGED event never occure when I click the checkbox. Thats y I tried putting a button and after checking check box if we press button the debugger will always show the value as FALSE. 
The button s click event will occur but it will show checkbox value as FALSE only. 
Please have a look at image, code and I can provide JS and CSS if you want.

[image: This is the image of the actual webpage. I want to do something that when you click on image it will appear one pop up window. There will be one check box on pop up window. when you change the state of pop up window it should notify user that state has been changed by message box.]
default.aspx:

```
<body style="background-color: #FFFF00">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table> 
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <a id="open-pop-up-2" href="#pop-up-2">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/234.png"/>
                    </a>
                </td> 
            </tr> 
        </table> 
    </div>
    <div id="pop-up-2" class="pop-up-display-content">
        <table style="width:100%;border-style:solid;border-width:1px"> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Onion" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show State" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>   
                </td> 
            </tr> 
        </table> 
    </div>
</form>
```

default.aspx.vb:

```
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data
Partial Class _Default
      Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
      Dim dt1 As New DataTable
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        MsgBox("State: Checked")
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("State: Unchecked")
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        MsgBox("State: Checked")
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("State: Unchecked")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

JS:

```
  $('#open-pop-up-2').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#pop-up-2').popUpWindow({
        action: "open",
        buttons: [{
            text: "Yes",
            click: function () {
                this.close();
            }
        }, {
            text: "No",
            click: function () {
                this.close();
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox must have `AutoPostBack="True"`, otherwise the change event will not fire until another control causes a postback.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Onion" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Comment: I have tried using that but it doesnt seem to work at all. Additionally I have tried using "ENABLE VIEW STATE" property as well.

Answer (score 0):

Been working in the same thread for very long and finally got that due to tricky pop up code [JQ] the value of check box status will never passed even though we set AUTOPOSTBACK true or false. So I had to change the POP up control and developed my own.

Thanks though.